# Why doesn't the concentration of one ion affect the concentration gradient of another ion across a plasma membrane?

Tags: physiology, cell-membrane

In the initial stages, some ion channels across the plasma membrane open to allow for ions to flow down their concentration gradient into or out of the cell. I understand that each ion's overall electrical potential across the membrane would affect the other ions', thus affecting their transport across the membrane. However, I don't understand why the concentration of ions aren't taken as an overall concentration because surely, if we are looking at diffusion of ions caused by Brownian motion, then all molecules on either side of the membrane would affect the other molecules on that respective side of the membrane?

Comment: Why do you think this about Brownian motion?

Comment: Because Brownian motion affects the random movement of the ions?

Comment: But, what aspect of Brownian motion makes you think the concentration of one ion affects the concentration of another?

Comment: Brownian motion is the random, uncontrolled movement of particles in a fluid as they constantly collide with other molecules (Mitchell and Kogure, 2006). Therefore, wouldn't the ions collide with one another and if there is a greater concentration of one ion outside a cell, it would increase the number of ions that can collide with the other ions, hence increasing the frequency of collisions, affecting the overall ion concentration gradient (is this a scientific term)?

Comment: No, it would not. I do not understand how you are going from frequency of collisions to a concentration gradient. In any case, the equations that are important are pretty well understood (Nernst, Goldman/GHK) - maybe best to start from those and try to understand what they say rather than speculation?

Comment: So is the point here that the concentrations of each ion only affect each other to the extent of their electrical potentials because the main thing that affects whether they can pass through the plasma membrane is the permeability of the leak channels/voltage-gated channels (in the case of diffusion).

Comment: Yes, that would be the main point evidenced by those equations.